# Merging File without space is faster than with space

Tags: c++, file, visual-c++, merge

So, I create a c++ executable file for merging files. I have 43 files with size of 100MB each. so a total of about 4.3GB.

Two cases:

One: If the file name are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ..., 43 it takes about 2 minutes to finish merging.

Two: If the file name are This File.ova0, This File.ova1, ..., This File.ova42 it will takes about 7 minutes to finish merging.

This is the same exact file, I just rename the file. Any idea what's wrong?

This is the c++ code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"

namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;

#pragma warning(disable : 4244)


typedef std::vector<std::string> FileVector;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int bucketSize = 3024 * 3024;

    FileVector Files;

    //Check all command-line params to see if they exist..
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if(!bfs::exists(argv[i]))
        {
            std::cerr << "Failed to locate required part file: " << argv[i] << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        //Store this file and continue on..
        std::cout << "ADDING " << argv[i] << std::endl;
        Files.push_back(argv[i]);
    }

    //Prepare to combine all the files..
    FILE *FinalFile = fopen("abc def.ova", "ab");

    for(int i = 0; i < Files.size(); i++)
    {
        FILE *ThisFile = fopen(Files[i].c_str(), "rb");     

        char *dataBucket = new char[bucketSize];

        std::cout << "Combining " << Files[i].c_str() << "..." << std::endl;

        //Read the file in chucks so we do not chew up all the memory..
        while(long read_size = (fread(dataBucket, 1, bucketSize, ThisFile)))
        {
            //FILE *FinalFile = fopen("abc def.ova", "ab");
            //::fseek(FinalFile, 0, SEEK_END);
            fwrite(dataBucket, 1, read_size, FinalFile);
            //fclose(FinalFile);
        }

        delete [] dataBucket;
        fclose(ThisFile);
    }
    fclose(FinalFile);

    return 0;
}
```

I run it through .bat file like this:

```
@ECHO OFF

Combiner.exe "This File.ova0" "This File.ova1" "This File.ova2" 

PAUSE
```

or

```
@ECHO OFF

Combiner.exe 1 2 3

PAUSE
```

both .bat file goes until the end of file name, I just wrote 3 files in here, otherwise it will be too long

Thank you

Comment: Have you run it several times to be sure that this is the comman behavior?

Comment: yes.. I run it almost 10 times each, and that's about the time I get.

Comment: Since you're using C++ and not C, you'd be better off with `fstream` than `fopen`.

Comment: why not use a tool already made for this ? `copy "This File.ova"+"This File.ova1"+"This File.ova2" "abc def.ova"`

Comment: So are the files in the same "place" for both tests?  That is do you rename the files for your test or did you copy them to another part of the disk?  If you copied it is probably a bad sector... or one going bad.

Comment: @Hogan File is same place

Comment: @AdrienPlisson is it the same as "type"? I did try using type before and it is slower than using c++

Comment: @AdrienPlisson I just try using copy/b filename, the behaviour and time is about the same as the c++ program that I created, filename with space takes more time than no space

Comment: @Harts then your problem may come from your filesystem, and not from your program...

Comment: @Harts put that in a batch file, where you call "copy" then "del". open a new question if you don't know ;)

Comment: The second set of files might be fragmented. Try defragmenting and check again. Another unrelated suggestion is to move allocation for databucket out of for loop.

Comment: I tested your code above. Both versions (short names and long names) run equally fast. Do you experience still the same behaviour?

Comment: I would recommend to test your code in different storage devices, to avoid specific problems in your device, like fragmentation, bad sectors, etc.

Comment: Seems like a file system feature. In case you use ancient Windows's the "long" filenames are encoded as more single file names ... (http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/fs/fat/fat-1.html). :)

Answer (score 1):

By default, Windows caches file data that is read from disks and written to disks. This implies that read operations read file data from an area in system memory known as the system file cache, rather than from the physical disk. Correspondingly, write operations write file data to the system file cache rather than to the disk, and this type of cache is referred to as a write-back cache. Caching is managed per file object:
More informations: [File Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364218%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)